# Find algorithm to produce integer points in a polygon

Tags: computational-geometry

Algorithm to find integer co-ordinate points inside the convex polygon.
I have tried to find the intersection of horizontal and vertical line but failed the time complexity.

Comment: which time complexity?

Comment: Duplicate of locked contest question asked yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2633898/generate-integer-points-inside-a-polygon